# Why do we assign types to objects that are different to an object's reference type in Java?

Tags: java, types

Java Newbie here

New instances are stored in variables. However, I see sometimes, that the type of the variable is different from the reference type of the object.

```
Y y = new x
```

Why do programmers do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface?r=SearchResults&s=1|373.7118

Comment: This Oracle Java tutorial on [Interfaces and Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html) may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because sometimes you have common interface for different implementations. For example

```
List<String> exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
```

and the other one

```
List<String> exampleList = new LinkedList<>();
```

Interface `List` provide for us the same methods for this two implementations, but how this methods works depends on implementation. Welcome

Answer (score 0):

Most time Y in your example is an interface so you can change later the Implementation without to change the rest of your application